# How do I enable my Query button in my view?

Tags: php, yii

I add another table field in my view , but the search button disappeared , How can I retrieve this form button ?

SaleItems = And a table mysql database.

```
<?php

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'formatter' => ['class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter','nullDisplay' => ''],
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            **[
            'attribute' => 'Data',
                'content' => function(SaleItems $model, $key, $index, $column) {
                    return date('d/m/Y', strtotime($model->sale->date));
                    },
                'header' => 'DATA'
            ],**
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with function(SalesItems ....), please show the related model and actionView

Comment: In grdi view there aren't query button normally .. what do you mean ? ..

Comment: Below ( Data) has a search field , he disappeared .

Comment: ok .. is the search field .. a few minutes and i post a poper answer ..

Comment: yes, it is the search field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search field disappears because in not setted properly in searchModel ..

for this you must extend the related modelSeacrh adding the relation with the related model and the filter for the field you need ..

for this you must  set in the base mode, the relation

```
public function getSale()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Sale::className(), ['id' => 'sale_id']);
}

/* Getter for sale data */
 public function getSaleData() {
  return $this->sale->data;
}
```

then setting up the search model declaring

```
/* your calculated attribute */
public $date;

/* setup rules */
public function rules() {
   return [
     /* your other rules */
    [['data'], 'safe']
  ];
}
```

and extending

```
 public function search($params) {
```

adding proper sort, for data

```
$dataProvider->setSort([
    'attributes' => [
         .....
        'data' => [
            'asc' => ['tbl_sale.data' => SORT_ASC],
            'desc' => ['tbl_sale.data' => SORT_DESC],
            'label' => 'Data'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

proper relation

```
 if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
    /**
     * The following line will allow eager loading with country data 
     * to enable sorting by country on initial loading of the grid.
     */ 
    $query->joinWith(['sale']);
    return $dataProvider;
}
```

and proper filter condition

```
// filter by sale data
$query->joinWith(['sale' => function ($q) {
    $q->where('sale.data  = ' . $this->data . ' ');
}]);
```

Once you do al this the searchModel contain the information for filter and the search field is showed in gridview

What in this answer is just a list of suggestion 
you can find detailed tutorial in this doc (see the scenario 2 and adapt to your need) 
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/